# App Store general link won't work on iOS Device

Tags: ios, app-store

I have use App Store general link to redirect user to our other apps using App Store iOS App. It's worked perfectly. But before 2-3 days and till now it some times works and some times shows a message "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

General App Store Link is: http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=APP_ID&mt=8

Have any one faced this type of problem?? 
Or what is the reason ? It's a problem of mine or Apple?

Answer (score 1):

This format works with just the ID, and survives name changes. On the device, it will open directly into the app store:

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=XXXXX&mt=8

Replace XXXXX with your app id.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use their link maker to do this....

http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker

i.e.
http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/plane-finder/id336477530?mt=8&uo=4

Comment: How can I make a link using only a 9 digit App Id?

Comment: Use the linkmaker tool.  Apple produce it for a reason! :-)

Comment: Yeah great...Now it's dependent of the country

Comment: @Plot you can remove the country code and it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to access your link from my iPod Touch and iMac, it gives me the error, `Your request produced an error. [newNullResponse]` You might just want to contact Apple with this error code. May I ask what app this links too? Maybe this app was taken down by Apple?

Comment: The link he has put there is a generic one with no ID son won't link to an app!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just use this link and replace any APP_ID using any of your app Id and open it from your device several times. You will see sometimes it works sometime not. 
http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=APP_ID&mt=8

Answer (score 0):

This works on my end (Xcode 5 - iOS 7 & Older - **Device**!):

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_APP_ID
```

Code snippet (you can just copy& paste it):

```
#define YOUR_APP_STORE_ID 123456789 // Change this one to your app ID

static NSString *const iOS7AppStoreURLFormat = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@";

[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: iOS7AppStoreURLFormat, YOUR_APP_STORE_ID]]; // Would contain the right link
```